# Why is the index only changing when I use different values?

Tags: python

I just started programming in Python, and I can't figure out how to make the index change if I want the values in the list to be the same. What I want is for the index to change, so it will print 0, 1, 2, but all I get is 0, 0, 0. I tried to change the values of the list so that they were different, and then I got the output I wanted. But I don't understand why it matters what kind of values I use, why would the index care about what is in the list?

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
justTesting = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
for item in justTesting:
    something = justTesting.index(item)
    print (something)
```

I'm using python 3.6.1 if that mattters

Comment: How is it supposed to tell one `[0, 0]` from another?

Comment: `index` is a newbie trap; you want `enumerate`.

Comment: Could you update your question with your expectation of what `index()` would do and what is the *expected result* of running your code?

Comment: Because the `.index` method gives you the index of the *first occurrence* of the item. Since all your items are the same, it's giving you the same exact index every time.

Answer (score 1):

Because each list (designated 'item' in your loop) is [0, 0] this means the line:

```
something = justTesting.index(item)
```

will look for the first instance of the list [0, 0] in the list for each 'item' during the iteration. As every item in the list is [0, 0] the first instance is at position 0.

I have prepared an alternative example to illustrate the point

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
justTesting = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
for item in justTesting:
    print(item)
    something = justTesting.index(item)
    print(something)
```

This results in the following:

```
[1, 2]
0
[3, 4]
1
[5, 6]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your list only contains `[0, 0]`!

So basically, if we replace all the variables with their values, we get:

```
justTesting = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

And using `.index(item)` will return the first occurrence of `item` if any. Since `item` is *always* `[0, 0]` and it first appears at `justTesting[0]`, you will always get 0! Try changing up the values in each list and try again. For example, this works:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for item in b:
    print(b.index(item))
```

Which returns:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

if the results were on a single line.

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/Jo41/6)

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html): the default for `index` is to identify the *first* occurence.  You need to use the `start` parameter as well, updating as you go: search only the list *after* the most recent find.

```
something = justTesting.index(item, something+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are iterating over a **list of lists**. 
Every item is actually a list, and you are executing `list.index()` method which returns the index of the element in the list.

This is a little tricky. Since you actually have 3 lists, of [0, 0] their values will be the same when testing for equality:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 0
>>> c = 0
>>> d = 0
>>> ab = [a, b]
>>> cd = [c, d]
>>> 
>>> ab is cd
False
>>> ab == cd
True
>>>
```

Now when you run `list.index(obj)` you are looking for the 1st index that matches the object. Your code actually runs `list.index([0, 0])` 3 times and returns the first match, which is at index 0.
Put different values inside a, b, c lists and it would work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
justTesting = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
for item in justTesting:
    something = justTesting.index(item)
    print (something)
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
ab = [a, b]
cd = [c, d]
ef = [e, f]
justTesting = [ab, cd, ef]
# Note that ab == cd is True and cd == ef is True
# so all elements of justTesting are identical.
#
# for item in justTesting:
#     something = justTesting.index(item)
#     print (something)
#
# is essentially equivalent to:
item = justTesting[0] # = ab = [0, 0]
something = justTesting.index(item) # = 0 First occurrence of [0, 0] in justTesting
                                    # is **always** at index 0
item = justTesting[1] # = cd = [0, 0]
something = justTesting.index(item) # = 0
item = justTesting[2] # = ef = [0, 0]
something = justTesting.index(item) # = 0
```

`justTesting` does not change as you iterate and the *first position* in `justTesting` at which `[0,0]` is found is always 0.

> But I don't understand why it matters what kind of values I use, **why would the index care about what is in the list?**

Possibly what is confusing you is the fact that `index()` does not search for occurrences of the `item` "in abstract" but it looks at the *values* of items in a list and compares those values with a *given value* of `item`. That is,

```
[ab, cd, ef].index(cd)
```

is equivalent to

```
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0].index([0,0])
```

and the first occurrence of `[0,0]` *value* (!!!) is at 0 index of the list for your specific values for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`.